# Get a variable from Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my config in test.js:

```
var still;
jQuery(function(still){
    still = 5;
});
console.log(still);
```

i want to show on console the variable 'still' (5), but is show to me 'undefined' !

can any1 help me :) !
Thanks

Comment: `jQuery(function()` will run after `console.log()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this code. remove still from function as argument

```
var still;
jQuery(function(){
   still = 5;
});
console.log(still);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your global `still` variable has been hidden by function's argument with the same name. Try this:

```
var still;
jQuery(function(stillTheArgument){
    still = 5;
});
console.log(still);
```

Please, reconsider your code as global variables are often not very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent clogging the global namespace, alternatively you could pass the variable via immediately invoked function expression like so:

The variable `still` will be available within the scope of the outer function.

```js
(function($, still) {
    $(function() {
        alert(still);
    });
})(jQuery, "STILL");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You are overriding the current global variable with your function variable as it currently stands.

Answer (score 0):

as charlietfl told consol statement executed first. and at that time value of `still` is undefined.

try initializing `still` like this, no need of onReady handler

> var still=5;
>   console.log(still);